# Call PHP Function in dynamic preview function

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form that allows users to enter data and before submitting a form, it lets them preview their work:

```
<form>
...
<textarea id="option-question" name="option-question" cols="65" rows="7"></textarea><br />
<button onclick="preview_mc('question')" type="button">Preview</button><br />
</form>
```

The preview function looks like this:

```
function preview_mc(part){
$("#preview-"+part).text($("#option-"+part).val()).html(function(index, old) { return old.replace(/\n/g, '<br />') });
var math = document.getElementById("preview-"+part);
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,math]);
}
```

(There are multiple "parts" that go into the function per page).

When I call the data from the database, it does a basic bbcode parsing with a parsing function, let's call it `parse_message`. How can I have the preview also go through the bbcode message parse? Would it be better to write a javascript function that emulates the parse message or to somehow call the PHP function through js? (If writing a javscript function is the best answer, help doing so would be greatly appreciated!)

Here is the message parse:

```
function parse_message($message){
$find = array(
'~\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]~s',
'~\[i\](.*?)\[/i\]~s',
'~\[u\](.*?)\[/u\]~s',
'~\[quote\](.*?)\[/quote\]~s',
'~\[url\]((?:ftp|https?)://.*?)\[/url\]~s',
'~\[img\](https?://.*?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp))\[/img\]~s'
);

// HTML tags to replace BBcode
$replace = array(
'<b>$1</b>',
'<i>$1</i>',
'<span style="text-decoration:underline;">$1</span>',
'<blockquote>$1</'.'blockquote>',
'<a href="$1">$1</a>',
'<img src="$1" alt="" />'
);

// Replacing the BBcodes with corresponding HTML tags
return preg_replace($find,$replace,$message);
}
```

Comment: `Send text via ajax to php` -> `convert bbcode` -> `return bbcode from php script to ajax call` -> `append` -> **`profit?`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Darren for the help. Here's the code I've ended up with:

Javascript:

```
function preview_mc(part){
    $("#preview-"+part).text($("#option-"+part).val()).html(function(index, old) { return old.replace(/\n/g, '<br />') });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'include/functions.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { "parse_message_call": $("#preview-"+part).text()},
        success: function(response) { $("#preview-"+part).html(response); var math = document.getElementById("preview-"+part); MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,math]);}
    }); 
}
```

PHP:

```
function parse_message($message){
    $find = array(
    '~\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]~s',
    '~\[i\](.*?)\[/i\]~s',
    '~\[u\](.*?)\[/u\]~s',
    '~\[quote\](.*?)\[/quote\]~s',
    '~\[url\]((?:ftp|https?)://.*?)\[/url\]~s',
    '~\[img\](https?://.*?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp))\[/img\]~s'
    );

    // HTML tags to replace BBcode
    $replace = array(
    '<b>$1</b>',
    '<i>$1</i>',
    '<span style="text-decoration:underline;">$1</span>',
    '<blockquote>$1</'.'blockquote>',
    '<a href="$1">$1</a>',
    '<img src="$1" alt="" />'
    );

    // Replacing the BBcodes with corresponding HTML tags
    return preg_replace($find,$replace,$message);
}

// for ajax
if(isset($_POST['parse_message_call'])) {
    echo parse_message($_POST['parse_message_call']);
}
```